# deleting column in a pandas dataframe deletes column in parent dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

When I create a pandas dataframe in python 2.7.10 like so:

```
data = {'name': ['Jason', 'Molly', 'Tina', 'Jake', 'Amy'],
        'year': [2012, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2014],
        'reports': [4, 24, 31, 2, 3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index = ['Cochice', 'Pima', 'Santa Cruz', 'Maricopa', 'Yuma'])
df
Out[48]: 
             name  reports  year
Cochice     Jason        4  2012
Pima        Molly       24  2012
Santa Cruz   Tina       31  2013
Maricopa     Jake        2  2014
Yuma          Amy        3  2014
```

and then I pass that dataframe to a new dataframe. Deleting a column in the new dataframe also deletes the column in the original dataframe, like so:

```
df1 = df
del df1['name']
df
Out[56]: 
            reports  year
Cochice           4  2012
Pima             24  2012
Santa Cruz       31  2013
Maricopa          2  2014
Yuma              3  2014
```

I've done it with multiple examples and the behavior is conserved. I'm trying to pass a table with many columns and remove only a couple that interfere with the subsequent analysis. I would like to retain the original dataframe, however, for other tasks and this recursive style column drop is preventing that. This is maddening! I believe I have done this before without seeing this type of behavior.

The following seems to work, but is more cumbersome.

```
df1 = DataFrame(data = df.values, columns = df.columns)
del df1['name']
df

Out[67]: 
             name  reports  year
Cochice     Jason        4  2012
Pima        Molly       24  2012
Santa Cruz   Tina       31  2013
Maricopa     Jake        2  2014
Yuma          Amy        3  2014
```

What is the best way to do this, and why the difference?

Answer (score 1):

This is python, not pandas.  When you do your assignment of `df`, you are actually pointing to the same object which can can confirm by looking at their memory location.

```
df1 = df

>>> id(df1)
4468641552

>>> id(df)
4468641552
```

You can create a new frame with the desired columns as follows:

```
df1 = df[['year', 'reports']]  # Select desired columns.
```

Delete a column to check behavior.

```
del df1['year']

>>> df  # original intact
             name  reports  year
Cochice     Jason        4  2012
Pima        Molly       24  2012
Santa Cruz   Tina       31  2013
Maricopa     Jake        2  2014
Yuma          Amy        3  2014

>>> df1  # new dataframe dropped column as expected
            reports
Cochice           4
Pima             24
Santa Cruz       31
Maricopa          2
Yuma              3
```

Comment: Thanks. I get it. That id() function is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

```
df1 = df.copy()
del df1['name']
```

Alternatively, you can do the following, which is probably better practice:

```
df1 = df.drop(['name'],axis=1)
```

Comment: these are perfect. I have a ton of columns to carry and only a couple to delete. The second option is nice and clean. Thanks!